# Is there an exisiting file sharing module that allows multiple file upload?

Tags: users, files

I've been doing some module searching and have had little luck. I was wondering if any of you knew of a file sharing module that has:

- Ability to upload multiple files at once
- Ability to share files and folders with specific users or all users
- Ability to delete or archive files
- Ability to upload most types of files

I found most of this functionality in [file depot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) but it doesn't allow multiple files to be uploaded at once.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from archiving files (I'm not even sure what that means for files in-use on a Node). [Media Browser Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) can do all of this:

> This is an enhancement module for the Media module. The focus is on UX
>   improvements for Media that won't bloat the main module. Currently the
>   additions are:
>
> - Adding tags to media when uploading
> - Pulling down title and description information from web based media sources
>
> The module is still in
>   development and more features should be coming soon. Based on the
>   feature requests in the issue queue and my own thoughts I would
>   organize the features for Media Browser Plus into two categories.
>   Functional and organizational.
>
> Functional:
>
> - Click and drag to select multiple files
> - Selecting multiple files with shift or ctrl
> - Searching media
> - Contextual links and actions
>
> Organizational:
>
> - Hierarchical taxonomy based organization e.g. “folders”
> - Uploading or importing a file structure into a taxonomy hierarchy e.g.
>     the directory tree in a zipped upload gets converted into the
>     “folders” taxonomy
> - Updating and applying taxonomies read from media
>     files e.g. tags added to images
> - Personal and public “folders”
> - Shared “folders” either by user or role
>
> If you have ideas or want to help
>   out, please feel encouraged to join in the issue queue. Feedback,
>   requests, testing, and patches are always appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly I've been told to keep looking to try and find something that isn't in beta still.

Answer (score 0):

There's a multiupload module for [FileDepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) which integrates [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload).

This allows for drag-and-drop multiple uploads from the browser into FileDepot.

The module is here: https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot_multiupload